# While, not looping in Python

Tags: python, django, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game with rounds. I'm using a while loop but it doesn't go back to the beginning.
I've tried declaring the variables inside of the while, outside, and many other things, but it just doesn't work.
I'll leave the code here.
Thanks for the help!

```
import random

computer_win = 0
user_win = 0
jugadas = 0

def play(computer_win, user_win, jugadas):
    while (jugadas < 3):
        user = input("What's your choice? 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors: ")
        computer = random.choice(['r','p','s'])        
        if user == computer:
            jugadas = jugadas + 1
            return( f'It\'s a tie. Round {jugadas}/3')
        if is_win(user, computer):
            user_win +=1
            jugadas = jugadas + 1
            return( f'You won! Round {jugadas}/3')
        else:
            computer_win +=1
            jugadas = jugadas + 1
            return( f'You lost! Round {jugadas}/3')


    if computer_win >2 or user_win>2:        
        if computer_win > user_win:
            "The computer won"
        elif user_win > computer_win:
            return "You won!"
        else:
            return "It's a tie ...."
        
        

def is_win(player, opponent):
    if(player == 'r' and opponent == 's') or (player =='s' and opponent =='p') \
        or (player =='p' and opponent == 'r'):
        return True
    

print(play(computer_win, user_win, jugadas))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using return in a loop will break it.
You should instead save your result to a variable and return it after your loop is finished.

Comment: I think that wouldn't work for what they are trying to achieve. They wants to print the string, not return it. If they save the result to a variable and return it after the loop is finished the user won't get instructions to keep playing after each round

Answer (score 0):

When you hit a `return` statement inside a function you'll exit the function even if the `return` statement is inside a loop. You should change all `return` statements to a `print()` function, `print()` function is useful for showing information to the user. `return` statement is useful for returning data to the program so that other components use it.

Another thing is you don't need to pass the function `play(computer_win, user_win, jugadas)` to `print()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statements will finish your function execution. They won't only exit your `while` loop, but your function will return a final value, a string in this case. Since you are reading the user input at the beginning of each iteration, I think you meant to use `print` instead. Take a look at the code below

```
if user == computer:
            jugadas = jugadas + 1
            print( f'It\'s a tie. Round {jugadas}/3')
        if is_win(user, computer):
            user_win +=1
            jugadas = jugadas + 1
            print( f'You won! Round {jugadas}/3')
        else:
            computer_win +=1
            jugadas = jugadas + 1
            print( f'You lost! Round {jugadas}/3')
```

As for the second portion of your code, bare in mind `return` won't print the results to the terminal, so maybe you want to use `print` there as well:

```
if computer_win >2 or user_win>2:        
        if computer_win > user_win:
            print "The computer won"
        elif user_win > computer_win:
            print "You won!"
        else:
            print "It's a tie ...."
```

In python you don't need to use explicit return statements, without return statements your function will finish executing and will return `nil`